# How to send static content in json response using maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to make static web service which is used by other like mobile developer. I need to make first static data like that

```
{"name":"shruti"}
```

so I start googling and find the editor or tutorial. First I download editor form here: https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

I mame my first program. I am using same inbuilt server *Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config*. My porm.xml looks like this:

*porm.xml:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test1</groupId>
  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>test1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

What dependancy I need to add in my pom.xml file so that when I hit url `localhost:test` it give json response  `{"name":"shruti"}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson for mapping your POJOs with json response.

dependency:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>`

You need to configure your app-servlet for converting your POJOs to and from json like this:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa //web service rest -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Now any controller annotated with `@ResponseBody` returns json of your returned POJO.

HTH!